# Is it possible to edit Bitcoin Core to broadcast non-standard transactions?

Tags: bitcoin-core, non-standard-transaction

Is it possible to edit Bitcoin Core to remove the `IsStandard` function and broadcast non-standard transactions?

Also is there a version like this available already?

Comment: I'm curious what you expect to accomplish with this?  AFAIK, if you broadcast nonstandard transactions on the mainnet, other nodes will disregard them and then eventually ban you.

Comment: Nodes ban you only if transaction is invalid. Relaying non-standard transactions is not violating bitcoin rules

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to edit bitcoin core to remove the IsStandard function and broadcast non standard transactions?

Yes, it is definitely possible. But I suggest not to patch core client, but create a small separate program for this task.

Comment: Is there any existing program i can use?

Comment: For the person who has skills in creating non-standard transactions it is very easy to write such program himself. I have such program of course

Comment: Could you provide a link?

Comment: link: mailto:alistermaclin@mail.ru :))))

Answer (score 0):

You can change your node to broadcast a non-standard transaction, but other nodes following consensus rules will not pass your transaction along. The only way to include a non-standard transaction in the blockchain is to contact a miner and ask them to include it in a block.

Bitcoin's testnet has IsStandard disabled. If you are trying to test scripts, it is strongly recommended to do it on testnet or regtest.